# matplotlib UserWarning When log axis is used in some cases

Tags: python, matplotlib

Basically I am running some optimisation algorithms that I have created using Numpy and I want to plot the log of the error against the number of iterations. Having done this with linear regression and having had no issues, it is very strange that I seem to get issues when doing the exact same thing with logistic regression. I get the following "warning":

> /usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/matplotlib/axis.py:1004:
>   UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval
>   padding; assuming no interval padding needed.   warnings.warn("Unable
>   to find pixel distance along axis for interval padding; assuming no
>   interval padding needed.")

However, when I don't use a log axis for the y axis, I don't get the error either. All the elements of the array that I am using are also positive, so it shouldn't have anything to do with taking the log of a non-positive number.

Has anyone ever encountered this before? Does anyone know what it may be referring to?

Thanks

Comment: It should be noted that plotting the exact same in matlab gives me no errors at all using semilogy.

Comment: With out _any_ code to reproduce this there isn't much anyone can do to help you.  What version of mpl are you using?

Comment: I have reported the issue here and there is code and data to reproduce it.

https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/4285

Answer (score -1):

not sure if this issue is still open, but I had a similar problem and updating seaborn fixed the issue for me. For you it might be matplotlib, depending which package you used for creating the graph.