# seaborn heatmap using log scale error: Unable to find pixel distance along axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap, colorbar

I get an error message when trying to creating a heatmap using seaborn.
This only happens if I use a log scale, which I need to do, otherwise the plot becomes largely non-informative. Although the plot does show (and appears to be fine), the colorbar on the side does not appear, even if I explicitly state cbar=True

The error message I get is

> UserWarning: Unable to find pixel distance along axis for interval
>   padding of ticks; assuming no interval padding needed.
>   warnings.warn("Unable to find pixel distance along axis "

I believe it is the same issue as reported here ([matplotlib UserWarning When log axis is used in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29300510/matplotlib-userwarning-when-log-axis-is-used-in-some-cases)), but without any code there was no answer in that case

Minimal code to reproduce below. If I comment out the norm=LogNorm() line, then it works fine.

```
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.colors import LogNorm

f = np.logspace (-10, -5, num=6)
l = np.logspace (-9, -18, num=10)

alpha_matrix = []
for F in f:
    newrow = [F/L**2 for L in l]
    alpha_matrix.append(newrow)


sns.heatmap(alpha_matrix,
            norm=LogNorm(),
            )
```

EDIT:
I am using Python 3.6, compiled in Spyder 3.2.6

EDIT2:
Updating seaborn fixed this

Comment: No error for me with this code [see image](https://postimg.cc/S2hJJ7Lw).
I also `import matplotlib.pyplot  as plt` and added `plt.show()`

Comment: weird. Your above addition does not help in my case (in my actual code I also have that).
I'll add specifications for python version and compiler, not sure if that makes a difference

Comment: Python 3.8.1. No error and graph is the same as @david's.

Comment: Updating seaborn fixed this